# What we call carousel background screen in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, carousel

What we call carousel background in kivy.
I try `carousel.display` its can,t work.

Comment: Can you provide more details like what you want to implement? Or what problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: i am creating project and i create a button to set wallpaper now i want if  carousel screen first  than set first picture in background wallpaper. So bro plz tell what we call carousel screen